Unable to prevent touching ticklabels in 3D plot
To prevent touching ticklabels, I want to raise the first zticklabel in my 3D plot. Despite I am successfully using this approach in 2D plots, it does not seem to work in 3D plots.
For illustration purposes, 3D and 2D plots are given in my MWE below. The MWE uses the scrbook documentclass for two reasons:

the production document is a scrbook
I was not able to get overlapping/touching tick labels with documentclasses article or standalone, which are commonly used for MWE.

What am I missing here? What prevents the first zticklabel to be raised?
MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.18,
    enlargelimits = false,
    width = 0.65\linewidth,
    height = 0.65\linewidth,
}

\newcommand{\shiftleft}[2]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {unable to raise zticklabel (in 3D plot)},
        %
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 1,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 1,
        zmin = 0.90,
        zmax = 1.10,
        %
        xlabel = {x axis},
        xlabel style={sloped},
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        },
        % shift first xticklabel --> working
        xticklabel={
            \ifnum \ticknum=1
                \shiftleft{2.5ex}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
                \else
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}
            \fi
        },
        %
        ylabel = {y axis},
        ylabel style={sloped},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        },
        %
        zlabel = {z axis},
        zticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=2,
        },
        % shift first zticklabel --> not working
        zticklabel={
            \ifnum \ticknum=1
                \raisebox{2.5ex}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
            \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi
        },
        view={210}{30},
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4ex}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {with raised yticklabel (in 2D plot)},
        %
        xmin = -0.5,
        xmax = 2.5,
        ymin = -0.5,
        ymax = 2.5,
        %
        xlabel = {x axis},
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        },
        %
        ylabel = {y axis},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        },
        %
        yticklabel={
            \ifnum \ticknum=1
                \raisebox{2.5ex}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
            \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi
        },
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{4ex}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {without raised yticklabel (in 2D plot, for reference)},
        %
        xmin = -0.5,
        xmax = 2.5,
        ymin = -0.5,
        ymax = 2.5,
        %
        xlabel = {x axis},
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        },
        %
        ylabel = {y axis},
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        },
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Add zticklabel={\ticknum} and you will see why. \ticknum is documented to start from 0, so \ifnum \ticknum=1 should also not work as the first one.

@hpekristiansen: Using zticklabel={\ticknum} shows that the 'first' ztick is at number 2. Adapting [...] \ifnum \ticknum=1 [...] to [...] \ifnum \ticknum=2 [...] shifts the corresponding label as desired. Nonetheless, I do not get the tick numbering. Why is the 'first' label at tick number 2 for the z-axis and at number 1 for the other axes? This is especially weird, as tick numbering should start at 0 according to the docs and your comment.

It should start from 0, so it is a bug unless we overlook something.
